# How can I execute AutoHotKey in a game

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

This is not for cheating. I am playing a point and click, single player game. The only goal I have is to move the cursor so it is visible on my TV.

My laptop is plugged into my TV screen, and only uses the TV screen (so despite having the potential of 2 screens, I only use 1).

An issue I have is, the mouse often gets lost outside the TV boundaries (I'm guessing Windows 10 still feels there are 2 monitors and despite not in use, still feels there is some value of my mouse being able to traverse something invisible to me).

So, a quick Google and I found I can use AutoHotKey to move the mouse into the middle of the screen

```
^!M::
CoordMode,Mouse,Screen
WinGetPos, winTopL_x, winTopL_y, width, height, A
winCenter_x := winTopL_x + width/2
winCenter_y := winTopL_y + height/2
;MouseMove, X, Y, 0 ; does not work with multi-monitor
DllCall("SetCursorPos", int, winCenter_x, int, winCenter_y)
;Tooltip winTopL_x:%winTopL_x% winTopL_y:%winTopL_y% winCenter_x:%winCenter_x% winCenter_y:%winCenter_y%
```

[Source](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=60433)

However, when I'm playing a game and execute the shortcut, it does not move the mouse. When I'm out of the game, it works as expected.

Is there a way to move the mouse into the middle of the screen from within a game?

Comment: Games often use MouseWarp* which keeps a virtual mouse always inside the game's screen [whether you can see it or not] I would suspect this may conflict. *Imagine a 1st person shooter - when you slide the mouse to the right, your character keeps on turning… even long after the mouse would ordinarily have hit the edge of the screen & stopped.

Comment: One way to get an instant ban from the official Autoit and AutohotKey forums is to ask any question about game automation, and I fear this would fall into that category. They are very strict.

Comment: Are you *physically* turning off the second screen, and leaving it usable in the OS as a result, or or you actually disabling it in Windows using <Windows>-<P> and selecting the relevant "PC screen only" or "second screen only" modes which should properly fix your problem without having to resort to kludgy scripts.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, this isn't game automation! This is a point and click game, and simply moving the mouse into the middle of the screen so we can point and click

Comment: @Mokubai only in Windows. So, right click desktop, display options and choose the "only use monitor 2" option

Comment: @MichaelHarvey there seem to be many benign threads on game automation in AHK forums ... however, many reports of multiplayer games being VERY intolerant about the use of such tools, and actively checking.

Answer (score 4):

Some games intercept keyboard and mouse events at a very low level,
so they will get them before AutoHotKey. You should look for another
solution for such games. Note also that using AutoHotKey can get you
banned in some games.

One possibility would be to disable the primary monitor in Windows.
This would avoid the cursor going into that monitor, keeping it
all in the second monitor.

Two methods for doing that:

- Use the keyboard shortcut
  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
  and select "Second screen only".
- Open *Settings > Display*,
  select the primary monitor and
  use the drop-down menu to select "Disconnect this display".

I have one small hesitation with my advice:
I can't test because I don't have multiple monitors,
so cannot be sure that Windows will let you disable the primary monitor.

Comment: Selecting "second screen only" will indeed properly disable the primary screen and as a result there is nowhere for the mouse pointer to go except the now only and singularly active "second" monitor.

Comment: THAT is the problem :) I have chosen second screen only :(

Comment: Strange. What about the second method? Is the resolution of this second monitor correct (there are no areas that fall "outside" the screen)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/) to restrict mouse movement.

I have used it in the past to restrict mouse movement in monitors.  Some games dont have the ability to lock the mouse cursor to the playable area.  This tool can fix that.